# Trouble using factorplot method of Seaborn

Tags: python, ubuntu, seaborn, kaggle

I am trying to run a Python notebook ([link](https://www.kaggle.com/elenapetrova/time-series-analysis-and-forecasts-with-prophet)). At line `In [18]:` where author plot some data using `Seaborn` I am getting an error

> ValueError: 'c' argument has 12 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 0, 'y' with size 0.

**In [18]:**

```
import seaborn as sns

# sales trends
sns.factorplot(data = train_store, x = 'Month', y = "Sales", 
               col = 'StoreType', # per store type in cols
               palette = 'plasma',
               hue = 'StoreType',
               row = 'Promo', # per promo in the store in rows
               color = c)
```

Seaborn Version:

```
seaborn==0.9.0
```

I looked at the web about this error but couldn't find anything useful. Please guide me in the right direction.

**Update**

Here is the minimal code for testing

```
import pickle
import seaborn as sns
# seaborn==0.9.0

with open('train_store', 'rb') as f:
    train_store = pickle.load(f)

c = '#386B7F' # basic color for plots

# sales trends
sns.factorplot(data = train_store, x = 'Month', y = "Sales", 
               col = 'StoreType', # per store type in cols
               palette = 'plasma',
               hue = 'StoreType',
               row = 'Promo', # per promo in the store in rows
               color = c)
```

Link to train_store data file: [Link 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15EJZJxDKAOZ890XetnGXQGh0usgB8Zsl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: What would be the output if you leave out `color=c`? The underlying issue  might be [#14113](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14113), but there is likely not any fix until the next seaborn version appears.

Comment: @DavidG Hello, I have created the minimal code for testing you can check the updated question for more detail

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Hello, I have tried removing `color=c` but the same error still appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make following changes in order to fix the issue

```
sns.factorplot(data = train_store, x = 'Month', y = "Sales", 
               row = 'Promo',     # per promo in the store in rows
               col = 'StoreType' # per store type in cols
               )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a change brought in with version 0.9.0.

In this version, factorplot is deprecated (implicitly) and the new catplot (category plot) has been implemented. You can still use factorplot in your code, but internally it will invoke catplot with the relevant arguments.

In catplot implementation, we cannot have 'hue' and 'col' or 'hue' and 'row' as same data fields when using the kind 'point' (line with points representing the mean value for the group).

Hence, you can change your code to either of the following options:

option 1:

```
sns.catplot(x="Month", y="Sales", hue="StoreType",col="Promo", kind="point", data=train_store)
```

option 2:

```
sns.factorplot(data = train_store, x = 'Month', y = "Sales",col = 'Promo',hue = 'StoreType')
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this simple change and got the desired plots

```
sns.factorplot(data = train_store, x = 'DayOfWeek', y = "Sales", 
               col = 'Promo', 
               row = 'Promo2')
```

I just discarded hue and pallete parameters.